# How to suppress subprocess output

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm running this code on a Raspberry Pi 3b+ (debian buster)

```
import subprocess

CAN_SET_DEV_BITRATE = ['sudo','ip','link','set','can0','type','can','bitrate','100000']
CAN_SET_DEV_UP = ['sudo','ip','link','set','up','can0']

try:
    subprocess.check_output(CAN_SET_DEV_BITRATE)
    subprocess.check_output(CAN_SET_DEV_UP)
except:
    pass
```

When this code runs, it outputs `RTNETLINK answers: Device or resource busy`. How do I stop it from printing this to console?

Comment: `stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL` on a new enough Python to have it, or `stderr=open('/dev/null', 'w')` on one that isn't.

Comment: BTW, the "in Python 2.7" duplicate is the one with the better answers, even if you're on Python 3 (there's a topical answer there too).